# In XForms, how to make all the fields readonly, except few fields?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I did the following to make a full page read-only, using [Making an Entire Instance Read-Only](http://dl.lib.brown.edu:8083/ops/doc/reference-xforms-2#d132e732):

```
<xforms:instance>
    <form>
        ...
    </form>
</xforms:instance>
<xforms:bind ref="instance('form-name')" readonly="true()"/>
```

But I have a requirement to enable just few fields. I tried such a code that was given for [Multiple binds on a given node](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-mips?pli=1#TOC-Multiple-binds-on-a-given-node) but was for the property "required". So this fails.

```
<xforms:bind ref="instance('form-name')/some-node" readonly="false()"/>
```

So, is there away to override the global read-only setting for the form instance for a few nodes alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, a bind with `readonly="false()"` has no effect, since this is the default, and it won't override another bind saying that this node is readonly, per the rules governing [multiple binds on a given node](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-mips?pli=1#TOC-Multiple-binds-on-a-given-node).

However, you can write a single bind that makes all the leaf elements in your instance (i.e. elements that don't contain any other element: `//*[empty(*)]`) read-only, except specific elements. For instance:

```
<xforms:bind ref="//*[empty(*)] except (/some/node, /some/other/node, …)"
             readonly="true()"/>
```