# Orbeon: Set all fields to readonly

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms

Is there a way in which I could, when an alert dialog is shown, disable all of the input fields, radio buttons, dropdowns, so mainly, to set them to readonly = true()?
And then, once clicking on the positive-choice of the alert dialog to set them back to readonly = false()?

I'm using FormBuilder and Orbeon 4.8.

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve this by adding an event on positive-choice for the dialog and referring to:

[In XForms, how to make all the fields readonly, except few fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079818/in-xforms-how-to-make-all-the-fields-readonly-except-few-fields?rq=1)